# What does "/dev/null" mean at the end of shell commands

Tags: linux, shell

What is the difference between the following commands?

```
ssh myhostname "command1; command2;...commandn;" 2>/dev/null
ssh myhostname "command1; command2;...commandn;"
```

1. what does `2>` mean?
2. what does `/dev/null` mean? I read somewhere that result of command will be write to file `/dev/null` instead of console! Is it right? It seems strange for me that the name of file be `null`!

Comment: 1. `man bash` is an interesting reading. 2. `/dev/null` is a special file that acts as a black hole; it doesn't take any disk space because everything that is put in it is actually discarded.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`2>` means "redirect standard-error" to the given file.

`/dev/null` is the null file.  Anything written to it is discarded.

Together they mean "throw away any error messages".

Answer (score 14):

1 is stdout. 2 is stderr.

Then sometimes you find `2>&1`, that means redirecting stderr to stdout.

Answer (score 5):

`/dev/null` essentially means "into the void", discarded.  The `2` you mention refers to error output, where it should be directed.

Answer (score 3):

2> means sending standard error to something

/dev/null means a bin

Answer (score 2):

1) Pipe everything on standard error to /dev/null (so ignore it and don't display it)

2) Dev null just points to nowhere, pipe anything to that, and it disappears.

Comment: There's other things stored in /dev/ such as pointers to filesystems (devices ie./dev/sda) and things like /dev/random where you can read from to get random data.

Comment: There are no pipes involved.  Redirections are not pipes.