# What does the `2>` mean on the Unix command-line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line-interface

```bash
scriptlist=`ls $directory_/fallback_* 2> /dev/null`
```

What exactly is the purpose of the `2>` part of the command?
I omitted it and ran the command, it just works fine.

And, if the output of ls is getting stored in /dev/null file, what exactly the variable `scriptlist` will contain?
When I executed the code, the output was in the variable and nothing was there in the file `null`. If we remove `2`, then the output is in the file instead of the variable.
Any idea what exactly this line of code doing?

Comment: `${script} $* >> $logfile 2>&1 < /dev/null`
What does `2>&1 <' represents here?

Answer: [In the shell, what is “ 2>&1 ”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Comment: I voted to reopen. "What is `2>`" is a specific programming question, the question gives an example, and provides context.

Answer (score 61):

File descriptor `2` represents standard error. (other special file descriptors include `0` for standard input and `1` for standard output).

`2> /dev/null` means to redirect standard error to `/dev/null`. `/dev/null` is a special device that discards everything that is written to it.

Putting all together, this line of code stores the standard output of command `ls $directory_/fallback_* 2> /dev/null` into the variable `scriptlist`, and the standard error is discarded.

Answer (score 9):

> any idea what exactly the '2' is doing over here

Here `2` is a file descriptor referring to `STDERR`.

`2> /dev/null` implies that `STDERR` be redirected to the null device [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null).

The complete line you've mentioned stores the output, i.e. `STDOUT` (ignoring the `STDERR`), returned by `ls $directory_/fallback_*` into the variable `scriptlist`.

Answer (score 6):

```
scriptlist=`ls $directory_/fallback_* 2> /dev/null`
```

As you have enclosed the whole line `ls $directory_/fallback_* 2> /dev/null` in backticks, 
the output of the [`ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) command is stored in `scriptlist` variable.

Also, the `2>` is for [redirecting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) the output of `stderr` to [`/dev/null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408619/what-does-dev-null-mean-at-the-end-of-shell-commands) (<strike>nowhere</strike>).