# Difference between shell command `ls –z >output.txt` and `ls –z 2>output.txt`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to learn shell commands. I know `ls >output.txt` saves the output to `output.txt`. However, what exactly does `ls -z >output.txt` do? In my book, it says it does Not save the output to `output.txt`. If this is true, where Does it save / print it? Also, is `-z` what causes it to not save it?

Lastly, what does `ls -z 2>output.txt` do? I know 2 refers to `stderr` (so the standard error). Does this mean it saves the error (if any) of `ls` in `output.txt`? If yes, where does the `stdout` get printed / saved? And what does the `-z` mean in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it `z` OR caps `Z`?

Comment: If you redirect `stderr`, then `stdout` goes, well, unredirected, that is goes to your terminal (or wherever you execute the command).

Comment: Putting `>output.txt` at the end of any command will save its standard output in the file. If the command doesn't produce any output, the file will be empty.

Comment: According to my manual, there's no `-z` option to `ls`. There's a `-Z` option, but it's only useful on SELinux.

Comment: Also, `ls` in my system (Linux, coreutils-8.22) doesn't support `-z` at all, while `-Z` causes printing SELinux context of each file. So perhaps your book describes a non-unix system and theoretically it might handle its commands quite differently from what  is called 'shell'

Comment: So if you want to redirect both `ls -z >output.txt 2>error.txt`. Perhaps you book is using `-z` which is generally not a `ls` option to generate some error content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 2> mean on the Unix command-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108895/what-does-the-2-mean-on-the-unix-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option `-z` for `ls` on Linux. So let's see what happens:

```
$ LANG=C ls -z  > /tmp/x
ls: invalid option -- 'z'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

The error message goes to STDERR which is connected to the terminal.
The standard output (which is empty) is redirected to /tmp/x so we get an empty file.

```
$ LANG=C ls -z  2> /tmp/x
```

In this second scenario STDOUT is connected to the terminal, however there is no output. The error message which got sent to STDERR lands in /tmp/x:

```
$ cat /tmp/x
ls: invalid option -- 'z'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```