# How to auto connect jumper or proxy and server with one command ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, command-line

I remember one of my friend is using `ssh` file configuration to make it be done, but I can't find the command that should be written in that file to achieve this result.

So what he did is just type the command

`ssh [alias of the server]`

and the shell automatically go to jumper (proxy) submit the password in there,
then go to the server and again submit the password there, so he doesn't need to re-enter password during ssh into the server.

Another question, is this able to be done for Windows server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Host jump
        User [username]
        HostName [ip address]

Host [server ip address] [server alias]
        HostName [server ip address]
        User [username]
        Port [port]
        ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p jump 2>/dev/null
```

Host Jump is a proxy server.

The command that will help you take a leap on the proxy server then continue to the server is ProxyCommand.

- %h: is using your username
- %p: is using your password from id_rsa.pub.

Reference: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is `2>/dev/null` means in that ProxyCommand?

Comment: Google much? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108895/what-does-the-2-mean-on-the-unix-command-line

Answer (score -1):

I've never tried this except with public key authentication, but assuming:

1. You want to ssh from *origin-box* to *target-box*
2. *target-box* has a network name of target.box.domain
3. *origin-box* is not authorized on *target-box*
4. *proxy-box* is authorized on *target-box*
5. *origin-box* is authorized on *proxy-box*

You ssh/config on *origin-box* would be something like:

```
Host target-box
    ProxyCommand ssh -q proxy-box -W target.box.domain
```