# What does `hash -r 2` do?

Tags: python, bash, shell, virtualenv, zsh

I found this code in virtualenv `activate` file:

```
# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

`hash -r 2` gives me an error in both bash and zsh. How does this code work? How does this code forget past commands?
Why might `$PATH` changes not be respected if we don't forget the past commands? Can you show me some example?

Comment: `2>` isn't `2 >`. There's probably a dupe around here somewhere.

Comment: `help  hash` has some useful information.

Comment: Arguably a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108895/what-does-the-2-mean-on-the-unix-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command isn't

```
hash -r 2
```

but rather

```
hash -r
```

The `2` is part of a [standard error redirect](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230/242096) to `/dev/null`, which essentially throws away error output.

You can read about Bash version of the `hash` builtin in `man bash`. Here's a relevant snippet:

> Any previously-remembered pathname is discarded.  If the -p option is supplied, no path search is performed, and filename is  used  as  the  full  filename of the command.  The -r option causes the shell to forget all remembered locations.