# Confusion with the redirection of output to 2>&1?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have checked couple of relevant posts regarding this in stackoverflow and other sources regarding the usage of 2>&1.

Unfortunately so far have not get my head around it completely.

I understand that 2 is the stderr and 1 is the stdout and we are combining with the 2>&1.

But my question is what is difference between:

```
1. mycommand > /dev/null       
2. mycommand 2> /dev/null      
3. mycommand > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I was thinking:

1. will redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null
2. will redirect stderr to /dev/null
3. will redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null

Relevant posts:

- [What does "/dev/null" mean at the end of shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408619/what-does-dev-null-mean-at-the-end-of-shell-commands))
- [i/o stream redirection on linux shell. how does the shell process a command with redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215401/i-o-stream-redirection-on-linux-shell-how-does-the-shell-process-a-command-with)
- What does “> /dev/null 2>&1″ mean? (http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/)

Comment: The first one just redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null`

Comment: What is your question/confusion exactly? You have almost answered it yourself, and you are actually correct. (**EDIT**: What you said before your edit was correct)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this:

**`mycommand > /dev/null`**

it will redirect channel 1 (which is stdout) of mycommand to /dev/null

**`mycommand 2> /dev/null`**

it will redirect channel 2 (which is stderr) to /dev/null

**`mycommand > /dev/null 2>&1`**

it will redirect channel 1 to /dev/null and then bind channel 2 (stderr) to channel 1 (stdout). Both will go into /dev/null

There is another one (just to complete)

**`mycommand 2>&1 > /dev/null`**

> In this second case, I bind (the child's) stderr to stdout (of the
>   parent) and then I find the child's stdout to /dev/null. The result is
>   that you now get the child's stderr output on stdout and the stdout
>   goes to the file. This is useful for processing stderr in a pipe, for
>   example. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215401/i-o-stream-redirection-on-linux-shell-how-does-the-shell-process-a-command-with))

Comment: So `mycommand > /dev/null 2>&1` and `mycommand 2>&1 > /dev/null` will be same-right?

Comment: Besides why we are saying  (the child's) stderr to stdout (of the parent). I thought you are binding parents stderr to the stdout of the parent and then stdout of parent is going to the dev/null. I shall check the link you have attached.

Comment: @Baishakh No, `cmd > /dev/null 2>&1` is very different than `cmd 2>&1 /dev/null`.  The first directs both streams to /dev/null. The second  directs stdout to /dev/null and stderr is sent to whatever stdout was before it was redirected to /dev/null. By 'the parent', chaos is referring to the shell that is parsing the command line, and 'the child' is the command being invoked.

Comment: I am now getting confused with the order of the command line. `mycommand > /dev/null 2>&1`. I thought IO redirection is left to right. And in this case we are completing the redirection to /dev/null at first and then doing the 2>&1.

Comment: @Baishakh, think of `x 2>&1 >/dev/null` this way: file descriptor 1 originally points to a physical file, say /dev/stdout. `2>&1` redirects fd 2 to whatever fd 1 points at (/dev/stdout). Then fd 1 is redirected to /dev/null. That last redirection does *not* affect what fd 2 is now pointing at. So, left to right is correct. `x >/dev/null 2>&1` works similarly: first fd 1 is redirected to /dev/null, then fd 2 is redirected to whatever fd 1 is currently pointing at.

Answer (score 4):

(errfile doesn't exist)

```
$ cat errfile
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open errfile.

$ cat errfile > /tmp/stream.out
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open errfile.


$ cat errfile > /tmp/stream.out 2>&1

$ cat /tmp/stream.out
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open errfile.

($ rm /tmp/stream.out)

$ cat errfile 2>&1 > /tmp/stream.out
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open errfile.

$ cat /tmp/stream.out

$
```

Order is thus important and `2>&1 1>out`  is different than `1>out 2>&1` due to stream redirection at shell interpretation. You shoud redirect in "reverse" order.  `stdout > final` than `source > stdout`

Comment: I am now getting confused with the order of the command line. I thought IO redirection is left to right

Answer (score 3):

Try these to get the differences:

```
echo "stderr" > /dev/fd/2 | >/dev/null
stderr
echo "stdout" > /dev/fd/1 | >/dev/null
```

both commands redirected to `/dev/null` but in first one we're writing to stderr which prints stderr but in second one it prints nothing

Answer (score 0):

1: redirect STDOUT to /dev/null, you use default file descriptor in this case, e.g. command [default]> filename, the default file descriptor is STDOUT.

2: redirect STDERR to /dev/null

3: redirect STDOUT to /dev/null and redirect STDERROR to STDOUT, which means both STDOUT and STDERROR will be redirected to /dev/null

### Hope the tips make you clear.

0, 1, 2...9 are file descriptors in bash. 0 stands for stdin, 1 stands for stdout, 2 stands for stderror. 3~9 is spare for any other temporary usage.

Any file descriptor can be redirected to other file descriptor or file by using operator > or >>(append).

Usage:  >

Please reference to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html